# While creating Azure App service via terraform throwing an error An argument named "zone_redundant" is not expected here

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm trying to create a zone redundant azure app service for high availability, but terraform validate throwing an error **An argument named "zone_redundant" is not expected here**.

My configuration looks like below

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
}

  resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "app-demo"
  location            = "Australia East"
  resource_group_name = "rg-app-service"
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  zone_redundant      = true

         
  sku {
    tier = "PremiumV2"
    size = "P1v2"
   capacity = "3"
  }

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Can anyone please advise me on this ?

Reference

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_plan#zone_redundant

Comment: What version of the terraform azurerm provider do you use?

Comment: @AndriyBilous - I'm using 2.46.0 version

Comment: Could you please try to use latest version 2.77.0?

Comment: Great.. Thanks @AndriyBilous. It's works now :).   Just wish to confirm with you, zone_redundant = true. will deploy the 3 instances across zones in mentioned location right ?

Comment: yes, App Service Plan will be created across zones in mentioned location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Terraform `azurerm` provider version **2.46.0**

`zone_redundant` option in `azurerm_app_service_plan` Terraform resources was added in Terraform `azurerm` provider version **2.74.0**, that's why you are getting error "An argument named "zone_redundant" is not expected here."

Please update Terraform `azurerm` provider version in your code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.74.0"
    }
  }
}
```